# What is the relationship between Riemannian and sympletic musical isomorphisms on the cotangent bundle?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, physics

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Its cotangent bundle naturally has a symplectic structure, and this gives rise to musical isomorphisms. These musical isomorphisms are the ones from physics that relate the Hamiltonian function and the Hamiltonian vector field.

What I am confused about is that if $M$ is a Riemannian manifold, then its cotangent bundle has an induced Riemannian metric. This means that in addition to the symplectic musical isomorphisms on the cotangent bundle of $M$, you have Riemannian musical isomorphisms. Since the symplectic musical isomorphisms do not depend on the Riemannian metric, there's no reason to think that they would be the same. But still, I wonder, is there any significance to these Riemannian musical isomorphisms? Do they have any physical significance for example? Is there an obvious relationship between them and the symplectic musical isomorphisms?

Comment: Consider the local case of a single finite-dimensional vector space. A symplectic form gives some identification with the dual. An unrelated inner product gives another. Without positing a relationship between the two (e.g. that they arise from a complex inner product) what else is there to say?

Comment: Let me ask more pointedly, then: why are the musical isomorphisms coming from the symplectic structure the ones that arise in Hamiltonian mechanics? What makes them more natural in this setting to the point of us ignoring the Riemannian musical isomorphisms? Is this just a cosmetic choice, or is there something more meaningful here?

Comment: The symplectic one is the one coming from the Poisson bracket, and the Poisson bracket’s alternating property is what makes Noether’s theorem true. In the generality of a Poisson manifold or Poisson algebra we can still do Hamiltonian mechanics without a symplectic musical isomorphism; the map only needs to go from the differential of the Haniltonian to the Hamiltonian vector field, not the other way.

Comment: I'm confused about your comment. The Poisson bracket is simply the Lie bracket by another name under the symplectic musical isomorphism, no? You can just as easily look at the Lie bracket under a Riemannian musical isomorphism... You'll still get anti-commutativity because that's a property of the Lie bracket...

Comment: I'd expect some concrete relation if, e.g., $M$ is Kähler. A priori the metric and the symplectic form can be completely unrelated (this is what Qiaochu is saying). Also I'd be careful talking about a metric on the *manifold* $T^*M$ (I'm sure this is not what you meant -- the Riemann extension of the Levi-Civita connection of the original metric in $M$ is a neutral pseudo-Riemannian metric on the manifold $T^*M$). Lastly, the Poisson bracket is *a* particular type of Lie bracket only, in the algebra of smooth functions, not directly on arbitrary vector fields.